# pytest html environment table data update

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest, pytest-html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPMx2.png)

How can I update the environment table data in pytest HTML?

```
tester : manoj
application : nopcommerce
```

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    config.stash[metadata_key]["foo"] = 'fuu'
```

&

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    config._metadata['Project Name'] = 'Nopcommerce'
    config._metadata['module Name'] = 'Registration'
    config._metadata['Tester'] = 'Manoj Das'
```

Both of these not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of pytest-html are you using?  Your first example is from v4.0.x and the second example is from v3.1.1 (I know this since I just upgraded from v3.1.1 to v4.0.2)

Unless you really need something in version 3.x.x.. I suggest you use the first one since it's from the latest version. Fire up your virtual environment and run the following in your command line:

```
$ pip install pytest-html --upgrade
$ pip install pytest-metadata --upgrade
```